# How to save localStorage chart values and load them?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, webforms

I'm using **Highcharts Stock library**, currently I'm trying to find a way to save `window.localStorage` after I save my chart in the GUI, I click the GUI **"Save Chart"** button, this will **save** as "highcharts-chart" in my **localstorage**

```
<li class="highcharts-save-chart" title="Save chart">
  <span class="highcharts-menu-item-btn" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://code.highcharts.com/8.1.2/gfx/stock-icons/save-chart.svg&quot;);"></span>
</li>
```

I would like to know if there's a way to **save** this data in my **database**, how can I pull this data into my backend if I'm using **asp.net webforms**, and how can Highcharts **load** this data once I want to **see it again.**

I'm currently saving different chart data with an **unique value** a **symbol reference** for the data and the **user id** that owns such data
I.E: `d1c8e2ca  -  AAPL -  1`

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <!-- Highchart css -->
    <style type="text/css">
        #container {
            max-height: 800px;
            height: 75vh;
        }

        /* Conflict with Bootstrap, not needed after v7.0.1 */
        .highcharts-bindings-wrapper * {
            box-sizing: content-box;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- Highchart css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.highcharts.com/css/stocktools/gui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.highcharts.com/css/annotations/popup.css">



    <!-- Highchart js -->
    <script src="/js/code/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/code/modules/data.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/code/indicators/indicators-all.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/code/modules/drag-panes.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/code/modules/annotations-advanced.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/code/modules/price-indicator.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/code/modules/full-screen.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/code/modules/stock-tools.js"></script>



    <!-- Chart -->
    <div id="container" class="chart"></div>

    









<!-- Chart Script -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    var data = <%=Session("chartData")%>;
    var symbol = "<%=Request("symbol").ToString()%>";
    var symbol_id_ohlc = symbol + "-ohlc";
    var symbol_name_ohlc = symbol + " Stock Price";
    var symbol_id_volume = symbol + "-volume";
    var symbol_name_volume = symbol + " Volume";

    // split the data set into ohlc and volume
    var ohlc = [],
        volume = [],
        dataLength = data.length,
        i = 0;

    for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
        ohlc.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][1], // open
            data[i][2], // high
            data[i][3], // low
            data[i][4] // close
        ]);

        volume.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][5] // the volume
        ]);
    }
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
        yAxis: [{
            labels: {
                align: 'left'
            },
            height: '80%',
            resize: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }, {
            labels: {
                align: 'left'
            },
            top: '80%',
            height: '20%',
            offset: 0
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shape: 'square',
            headerShape: 'callout',
            borderWidth: 0,
            shadow: false,
            positioner: function (width, height, point) {
                var chart = this.chart,
                    position;

                if (point.isHeader) {
                    position = {
                        x: Math.max(
                            // Left side limit
                            chart.plotLeft,
                            Math.min(
                                point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - width / 2,
                                // Right side limit
                                chart.chartWidth - width - chart.marginRight
                            )
                        ),
                        y: point.plotY
                    };
                } else {
                    position = {
                        x: point.series.chart.plotLeft,
                        y: point.series.yAxis.top - chart.plotTop
                    };
                }

                return position;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'ohlc',
            id: symbol_id_ohlc,
            name: symbol_name_ohlc,
            data: ohlc
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            id: symbol_id_volume,
            name: symbol_name_volume,
            data: volume,
            yAxis: 1
        }],
        responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 800
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    rangeSelector: {
                        inputEnabled: false
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Napal, So do you want to save chart options in localStorage or in your database?

Comment: In my database, but I think I need to retrieve the data from localstorage and place it just like that in the chart once I want to load it, however, how do I load that data to my chart?

Comment: I have prepared this example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eqdxns3p/ Please check it and let me know if you solve your problem.